# Can we do DFS without backtracking?

Tags: depth-first-search, backtracking

Is it possible to implement DFS algorithm without using backtracking method? If it is, then please explain how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The DFS algorithm cannot be implemented without using backtracking.

Think about it, the core nature of DFS is to explore as far as possible from a root node, until it has to go back to explore other potential paths. This means as soon as the algorithm hits a leaf node, you will be **backtracking** to the node before that path was explored to find other options.

To further justify this https://medium.com/@andreaiacono/backtracking-explained-7450d6ef9e1a defines backtracking as "a general algorithm ... that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons each partial candidate (“backtracks”) as soon as it determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.". See how this applies to DFS.